# In workgroup environment not able to add secondary server user in sql server at database level from primary server

Tags: sql-server

we have 3 nodes (primary server ,secondary server ,witness server) in workgroup environment, we are using sql server 2012, we have used the concept of mirroring the so that secondary server will take over the responsiblity in the case  of primary server failover. when failover is happening and secondary machine is taking over we are deleting the the database of secondary machine and restoring the database backup of primary machine in secondary machine but this restored database does't have the user of secondary server.

**Question 1)**  Is there any way to add secondary server windows user to sql database from primary server ,In primary server secondary server user names are not listing down may be because servers are in workgroup . 
example of user :- secondarymachinename\group

**Question 2)** Is there any way to add user to database resored with (no recovery) mode.

If you feel anything is still unclear please let me know.

Comment: why you need to use windows user? SQL user can work also

Comment: It's a big product they developed it long back with windows authentication so we can't change it now